# When is there a solution to these coupled eigenvalue equations?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvector, eigenvalues

I am trying to find the fixed point of a dynamical system, which requires solving two coupled eigenvalue-like equations.  These equations are, in general, overconstrained.  I'd like to have a simple criterion for whether or not there will be a solution.

Assume that there are two given matrices, $A$ and $B$.  I want to find a diagonal matrix $X$ and a nonzero vector $y$ such that the following two conditions are satisfied:
\begin{align} X A y &= y \\ (A - X B)y &= 2y \end{align}
(All matrices are of size $n \times n$, and $y$ is of size $n$.)  Please feel free to suggest any reasonable simplifying assumptions if it helps solve the problem.

Here is a hand-wavy argument to suggest that the problem is slightly overconstrained.  I have $2n$ free variables, and the two conditions above impose $2n$ constraints, suggesting that there is generally a solution.  However, they have the obvious solution $y=0$, which I am excluding, so it's almost as if there are $2n+1$ constraints.  Therefore, it seems like solutions to this problem should be possible if one extra condition is satisfied by $A$ and $B$, which would make one of the constraints degenerate.  (Yes, this is extremely wishy-washy and possibly wrong.)

I posted a related question [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/144392/condition-for-two-matrices-to-share-at-least-one-eigenvector) in the hope that it would give me some insight into this problem, but so far I am still stuck.  Thanks in advance for any ideas!

Comment: maybe you can require the vector $y$ to satisfy $\|y\|=1$; that will exclude the $y=0$ solution...

Comment: Of course.  There are many ways to impose the $f \ne 0$ condition, but the main point is that it makes the system slightly overconstrained.

Comment: Actually, what I was hoping with $\|y\|=1$ is flip it around into a fixed-point iteration so that we can invoke Brouwer's theorem to guarantee existence of $X$ and $y$...

Answer (score 3):

I tried the $n=2$ case, using Maple to find a "plex" Groebner basis for the equations.
The result is rather complicated, and too large to show here.  The first member
of the basis, for example, is $y_1$ times an irreducible polynomial of $143$ terms and total degree $8$ in the
entries of $A$ and $B$, which must be $0$ in order to have a solution with $y_1 \ne 0$.  So I don't think you'll get a "simple" criterion.

EDIT: You want the $2n \times n$ matrix
$$ \pmatrix{X A - I\cr A - X B - 2 I\cr}$$
to have rank $< n$.  That is equivalent to all its ${2n} \choose n$ $n \times n$ submatrices (obtained by selecting $n$ of the rows) having determinant $0$.  Each of those determinants is a polynomial ...

Comment: Thanks!  I didn't know about Gröbner bases.  Somehow this seems like it can't possibly be that complicated, but maybe it is.

Comment: It's occurs to me that you can construct a scary-looking polynomial in all eight variables just using simple ingredients like $\det(A)$ or $\det(B-I)$ or something, and we could be seeing a complicated result that has a simple origin.  But that still doesn't bring us any closer to a solution.